# Defining multiple preprocessor constants for multiple language solution

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, msbuild, powershell-2.0

I am currently working on a build script for a system using powershell 2.0 and MSBuild. The basic idea is that our librarian can double click and build it in its various configurations. Unfortunately, for contract reasons, we have to configure the project with preprocessor directives and some configurations require several different constants to be defined, which we do by using powershell to generate a command such as:

```
msbuild.exe thing.sln /p:DefineConstants="FOO;BAR" /t:Rebuild
```

That works fine and dandy until it hits a vb project (this thing is a monolithic mass of vb, c, c++ and C#). Than I get an error like:

> FOO; ^^   ^^ BAR; is not valid: Character is not valid

I am assuming it has to do with VB.NET liking its preprocessor constants colon separated rather than semi colon seperated. My question(s) is(are) then: Is there a language agnostic (at least VB/C/C++/C# agnostic) way to define these preprocessor constants through DefineConstants ? If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

In a lesson of trusting one's own instincts, I have found that a comma works.